# Can't center web page in IE

Tags: css

[My website](http://spectrasoft.com) is left-aligned in IE 8 and 9 when it should be centered like it is in Chrome and Firefox. I have tried standard solutions like the one below with no luck. There are multiple style sheets on the page -- perhaps there's a conflict? Any help would be appreciated...

```
*{  
    margin:0;  
    padding:0;  
}  

body{  
    text-align:center; /*For IE6 Shenanigans*/  
}  

#wrapper{  
    width:960px;  
    margin:0 auto;  
    text-align:left;  
}
```

Comment: i dont see a difference between ie9 and firefox or chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Although you define the following CSS in your style.css stylesheet-

```
#wrapper{
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:left;
position:relative;
}
```

There is no corresponding element with an ID of wrapper on the page, your #header, #nav, anonymous content and #footer divs are all direct children of the document body.

The link as a child of the h1 with ID "logo" almost certainly needs to have a left value (probably of zero) added in addition to the existing "top" value as it is overlapping your phone number.

You also appear to be encoding the conditional comments added as the first child of body in IE8 as -

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]--> <!--[endif]-->
```

Is appearing in the page.

Have you tried using either [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) or [Firebug (for Firefox)](http://getfirebug.com/) to inspect your code?

Comment: Looks like multiple .container elements - perhaps they need that CSS.